# how to handle the Status bar Orientation in ipad with ios 7 beta 6 with landscape left orientation

Tags: ios, ipad, ios7, ios-simulator

I developed my applicaton(only landscape support) in Xcode 4.0 and successfully upgrading to every new IOS, but with ios 7 as we know that statusbar is having a new change that transulant bar on top of view like shown in below image

[image: Image with fullscrenn view and statusbar on top of that in ios 7]

But i resolved that by changing the viewcontrollerbasedstatusappearance parameter value as NO in plist and also window origin x coordinate vlaue to 20 pixels( why x coordinate means, my app forcelyfully launches in landscape orientation), its working in landscape right orientation.And result is below shown in below pic and the code is here

```
 -(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary*)launchOptions{

    self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds] autorelease];
    if (DEVICE_IS_IPHONE || DEVICE_IS_IPHONE5)
    {
        [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarHidden=YES;
    }
    else if(DEVICE_IS_IPAD)
    {
        [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarHidden=NO;
        if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 7) {

            [application setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleLightContent];
            self.window.clipsToBounds=YES;
            self.window.frame=CGRectMake(self.window.frame.origin.x+20, self.window.frame.origin.y, self.window.frame.size.width-20, self.window.frame.size.height);
        }
    }
    mLoginController = [[LoginViewController alloc]init];
    mNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc ] initWithRootViewController:mLoginController];
    self.window.rootViewController = mNavigationController;
    [self.window addSubview:[mNavigationController view]];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    [mLoginController release];
    return YES;
}
```

And in loginviewcontroller with the view as shown below, I am using loadview method to override the controllers view like below, for your info i changed this to use directly viewdidload even though same problem is occuring.

```
-(void)loadView{    
    CGSize theSize = CGSizeMake(1, 1);
    CGRect theFrameRect = [UtilityMethods getAbsoluteFrameForSize:theSize];//i will get the exact    
    screen size based on device
    UIView *theLoginView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 40, theFrameRect.size.width,   
    theFrameRect.size.height)];
    self.view = theLoginView;
    self.view.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin;
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
}
```

[image: Image with normal view as in ios 6 after resolving and the statusbar frame value is like this {{0-y, 0-x}, {20-h, 1024-w}}]

But if i rotate to landscape left again the status bar is comming on top of the view and the frame of the status bar is sit at bottom like shown in below pic.You can observe the black view at bottom in the below pic which I hope window frame of status bar.

[image: with status bar frame as {{748-y, 0-x}, {20-h, 1024-w}}]

So please let me knwo any one how to handle this to support both ios 6 & 7 as soon as possible.Thanks in Advance.

Comment: It would be more appropriate to ask this on the [Apple Dev Forums](https://devforums.apple.com) since the iOS 7 SDK is under NDA.

Comment: Thank u Steve i will post there also..

Answer (score 1):

I would attach an observer on the `UIViewController`'s view's `bounds`:

```
- (void) viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self.view addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"bounds" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:NULL];
}

- (void) observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context
{
    if (object == self.view && [keyPath isEqualToString:@"bounds"]) {
        //redraw your status bar background
    }
}
```

Then `removeObserver` in `dealloc`. This way you can always keep the status bar background up to date with the current appearance.